# Check whether or not a program is installed without closing before finishing execution

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I have this program that aims to evaluate if a program (in this case DOSBox) is installed on the system. In the event that the user answers yes (they want it downloaded) as a test, and displays a message echo Congratulations, you have entered the second if! otherwise another message appears saying echo You cannot run DOS programs on 64-bit systems.

The program closes immediately after I open it.

I am running it from a bat file

```batch-file
@echo off
echo Simple verification started.

where dosbox >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo DOSBox is installed on the system.
) else (
    echo DOSBox is not installed.
    pause
    set /p response=DOSBox is not installed. Do you want to download it? (y/n):
    if /I "%response%"=="s" (
        echo Congratulations, you entered the second if!
    ) else (
        echo You cannot run DOS programs on 64-bit systems.
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: You have a delayed expansion issue, because you are both defining and referencing a variable within a parenthesized code block. You could however fix it better by chaging your use of `set /p` to the use of the `choice.exe` utility, and compare the response using `ErrorLevel`.

Comment: And how would that be applied to the code?

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `choice` /? and `if /?` to read the documentation on how to use the commands.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, then read the output!

Comment: But I wanted to execute it from a bat file

Comment: The `)` is closing your `if` statement too early.`set /p response=DOSBox is not installed. Do you want to download it? (y/n):`. Escape it: `set /p response=DOSBox is not installed. Do you want to download it? (y/n^):` or (even better) use preferred quoted syntax: `set /p "response=DOSBox is not installed. Do you want to download it? (y/n): "`. and even even better, use `choice` (like already suggested) (beside the mentioned [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028))

Comment: I should also highlight that your `where` command line could be improved. If you read its help information, (`%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /?` in a Command Prompt window), you should note and use its `/Q` option, to return only an ErrorLevel. You should also use the actual full name of the file `DOSBox.exe`. It should also be mentioned that this only determines whether a filename `DOSBox.exe` exists within the current working directory, or a location listed within the `%Path%`, (at the time it is invoked). It most certainly does not indicate that the program `DOSBox` has been installed.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro what makes you think we are giving you information that doesn't run in a [tag:batch-file]?